# What is the name of the Master of Lake-town?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

I know that Tolkien never defined the Master of Lake-town to have a name. I want to have him appear in a game I organize and it would be very awkward if I could not use a name for him.

With the upcoming movie in mind I'd like to use a name that is established, even if it's non-canonical.

- Is there a canonical name mentioned in other writings of J.R.R. or C. Tolkien?
- Is there a non-canonical but commonly used name known for the Master of Lake-Town?
- Or is it already known what Peter Jackson will use as a name?

Comment: yes it did. I wanted to wait if there came another. I go over my questions regularly and check for missing accepts. but thanks for the reminder.

Comment: No problem. I understand completely about waiting for answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [The Lord of the Rings wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Master_of_Laketown):

> In the play adaptation of The Hobbit by Edward Mast, The Master of Laketown is named Maxwell, though this is not considered canon. In the Peter Jackson adaptation of The Hobbit, set to release in December 2012, Stephen Fry has been cast to play the Master of Laketown.

Nothing yet seems to have been released on a name for the upcoming Hobbit movie, and J.R.R. Tolkien never seems to have given a canonical name for him.

Answer (score 2):

The Master was never given a name in Tolkien Canon, for whatever reason that may be. Some adaptions of The Hobbit have named the character: among them being a videogame from 2003, in which the Master was named Calamar.

Comment: It'd be nice to see a source (at minimum,  a link) stating the fact about 'Calamar'